# Html Agility Pack asp.net mvc Xpath

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this html:
[Picture with html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q30G.png)

I need to show in my View :  Бавария Майнц  -2.25

I try write this:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(
                "https://www.parimatch.com/sport/futbol/germanija-bundesliga");

            foreach (HtmlNode table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='oddsNote']/table/tbody"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {
                    HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");

                    if (cells == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Results += cell.InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but my table always null. Where I have a mistake?
and what are the other options to output in View except Viewbag?

---

My HTML:

```
<div id ="z_container">
<div id = "Z_contentw">
<div id = "OddList">
<form name ="f1" id = "f1">
<div class = "container_grey">
<div class = "wrapper">
<table id = "4529899" class ="dt_twp">
  <tbody class ="row1 processed">
  <tr class ="bk">
  <td> "02/03"  <br>  "21:00"</td>
  <td class ="l"> <a class ="om" id ="a738">Bavaria  Mainc</a></td>
  <td> <b 3.5></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class ="row2 processed">
  <tr class ="bk">
  <td> "03/03"  <br>  "19:00"</td>
  <td class ="l"> <a class ="om" id ="a739">Roma  Milan</a></td>
  <td> <b 2.5></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to show: 02/03 21:00 Bavaria Mainc 03/03 19:00 Roma Milan

Comment: Post us the HTML in here, and not as a Picture + I can't see any div with the @id of "oddsNote"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath has an id that is not in the html you provided other than that
If you want the text in one line as you showed then it can be

```
  var text =  string.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='bk']//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t=>t.InnerText));
```

If you want to model the data then use the indices of the td, the first one has the time the second has the teams so create a simple model

```
class FootballMatch
{
   public string Time;
   public string Teams;
}
```

and get the data using the following

```
var matches = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='bk']").
                Select(tr => new FootballMatch() {
                    Time = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]//text()").Select(t => t.InnerText)),
                    Teams = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[2]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and write there after that , please, watch this topic tomorrow.

Comment: But if I use one line all works, but I think model is more correct.   If I use one line   I see this   http://i64.tinypic.com/2vt8dv5.png

Comment: @andrey1567 i can't magically imagine how your Html looks like, based on the html you provided this works as expected, if you want further help share the a link with full html, make sure you process the text with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` method and set your WebClient instance encoding to UTF8

Comment: Yes, I did it ,it works, but unfortunately only with one line.  Matches is null, I will try decide this problem .  Thanks for your help!

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode need only string parameter and return string. But matches is IEnumerable.  How this fix?

Comment: @andrey1567 you can iterate an IEnumerable using foreach or Linq Select.

Comment: foreach (var a in matches)
            {
                a.Time = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(a.Time);.........
            }   Whats wrong?